# PyInstaller includes almost a Gigabyte of unneeded Icons and Themes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyinstaller

My Python script on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 is some 200kB and uses PyQt4, matplotlib and numpy as the major modules. Out of this Pyinstaller creates a working 'dist' directory of a shocking 800 MegaBytes!

Inspecting this dir with a disk usage analyzer tells me it consists of some 750MB of icons and themes! Attempting to remove some themes from my computer fails, as I would cripple my system.

I need only a very minor set of the icons or themes for my script, so how can I get rid of them? I don't see any provision in PyInstaller to exclude them?

Comment: This behavior is generally caused by one of the hooks that is being used.  You can look into the hooks and possibly find which one is picking up the files.  You can also use something like VirtualBox to build a build machine which is more tailored to this app and does not have all of the extra files.

Comment: I find some 400 hooks, each one a Python script which needs to be understood before one can tell what it does. "Possibly" finding something is well expressed :-/

Comment: The hooks are named the same as the module they hook, and they are all very similar.  But yes, I was leaning towards building a build machine, for the reason that it will make everything more predictable.

Comment: I have now figured out that I can make wild guesses at the module names, which I do not want with - in the *spec file - e.g. 'excludes=['wx', 'gtk+', 'Tkinter', 'gtk', 'gdk', 'gtk2', 'gtk3', 'cairo', 'wayland', 'xinerama', 'share', 'icons', 'atk', 'pango', 'pil', 'PIL'],' but the myriads of icons and themes remain. But I can simply delete the whole folder of them, as exactly nothing of it is needed :-/